# In TeamCity, how do I install the right TypeScript library to match my Visual Studio 2017 project?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2017, teamcity

I upgrade my Visual Studio 2017 web project to use TypeScript 2.6 instead of 2.5. Once I checked-in and ran the build on TeamCity, I got the following warning:

`[Warning] ... Your project specifies TypeScriptToolsVersion 2.6, but a matching compiler was not found. The latest available TypeScript compiler will be used (2.5). To remove this warning, install the TypeScript 2.6 SDK or update the value of TypeScriptToolsVersion`

How do I install TypeScript 2.6 SDK on a TeamCity build agent?

[image: Figure 1: The web project properties is where the TypeScript version is specified.]

*Figure 1: The web project properties is where the TypeScript version is specified.*

Answer (score 1):

To install a particular version of TypeScript on a TeamCity build agent, simply copy the appropriate TypeScript library directory to the build agent.

1. Find where Visual Studio installed TypeScript on your machine. For example, TypeScript was installed at this directory for me: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript`
2. Copy the directory that matches the TypeScript version you wish to put on the TeamCity build agent. For example, copy the folder labeled `2.6`
3. Find where Visual Studio installed TypeScript on your TeamCity build agent. For example, the path was the same for me as my local machine: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript`
4. Paste the directory from your local machine into this directory on the build agent.

That is all that is required. Run the build again on TeamCity and your mismatch TypeScript warnings should be absent.